# No space left on device when upgrading Debian 7 to 8

Tags: linux, debian

I want to upgrade my Debian server from 7 to 8. It failed, and the error was :

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64_3.16.7-ckt11-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/md/dm-cache-cleaner.ko' to '/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/md/dm-cache-cleaner.ko.dpkg-n
ew': failed to write (No space left on device)
```

I looked up with `df -h` my partitions :

```
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1          323M  203M  103M  67% /
udev                10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs              1.2G  232K  1.2G   1% /run
tmpfs              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs              3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda9           49G  180M   46G   1% /home
/dev/sda8          368M   11M  339M   3% /tmp
/dev/sda5          8.3G  778M  7.1G  10% /usr
/dev/sda6          2.8G  317M  2.4G  12% /var
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1  539G  4.9G  507G   1% /cache
```

So I saw my sda1 is kind of small, but I'm not sure. Could anyone tell me where is the problem and how can I make this upgrade?

**Additional info:**

The output of `df -i`

```
Filesystem          Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1            85344   6598    78746    8% /
udev               1538700    403  1538297    1% /dev
tmpfs              1540254    333  1539921    1% /run
tmpfs              1540254      1  1540253    1% /run/lock
tmpfs              1540254      2  1540252    1% /run/shm
/dev/sda9          3235840     26  3235814    1% /home
/dev/sda8            97536     13    97523    1% /tmp
/dev/sda5           549440  29880   519560    6% /usr
/dev/sda6           183264   3328   179936    2% /var
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1 35840000 332679 35507321    1% /cache
none               1540254      2  1540252    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

I didn't reboot the server yet, and when I type `cat /etc/issue` I saw this machine is already in version 8, though it's not possible.

---

Thanks for Michael's help, this is what I got by `apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

And when I ran `apt-get -f install`, it came back to the same error "No space left on device".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `df -i`.

Comment: Note that I would **strongly advice against rebooting** your system at this point; it may be in an inconsistent state. If we can fix whatever the problem is with `/` (which shouldn't be very difficult) you should be able to resume the upgrade.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling Ok, I already added info from dh -i

Comment: Thanks. This is confusing though, because the two main causes of getting *No space left on device* is either running out of storable bytes ("disk full"), or running out of usable inodes, and your problem seems to be neither. What happens if you simply re-run the same apt-get upgrade or apt-get dist-upgrade that ended with the error in your question? Note that /etc/issue is just one more file installed by one of the basic system packages (specifically `base-files`), so that it says Debian 8 just means that it has been upgraded to the Jessie version, not that your whole system has been upgraded.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling It tells me to run apt-get -f install, and the same error "no space on device" appears again.

Comment: This really is confusing. At this point I have no really good suggestion. However, have a +1 for a well-written question.

Answer (score 2):

You need about 160MB free on /lib to install a new kernel including the modules; you only have about 100MB free. `dpkg` removes any partially-installed stuff while cleaning up in such cases.