# Debian server not successfully upgrade

Tags: linux, debian

I did an upgrade for my Debian server from version 7 to 8.

The upgrade was very messy, mainly due to an issue that I wrote [here](https://superuser.com/questions/939913/no-space-left-on-device-when-upgrading-debian-7-to-8). I could almost tell the upgrade is not successful. But when I check the version, it says I'm already Debian 8.0.

Then I removed the `linux-image-amd64` package, cleaned up my apt-get by `apt-get -f install`, and want to redo the upgrade. Now it shows no errors. When I type `apt-get dist-upgrade`, it tells me `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.` So I'm stucked in this fake version 8.0.

I want to know how can I redo the upgrade in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: You can verify by running `apt-cache policy $(dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}') | less`. If there's no more instances of `wheezy` in the output, you're probably good.

Comment: @geewee thanks for your reply, but I'm sure the installation is not completed because the deb file did not even get unpacked. How can I remove the version and get a new install ?

Comment: Have you done `dpkg --configure -a` to resume configuration of unpacked packages? If your system isn't very broken, `apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade` should resume the upgrade where it left off.

Comment: @geewee Yes I've tried this, it kept telling me 0 not upgraded when I use `apt-get dist-upgrade`. It's weird. `lsb_release -a` and cat debian_version tell me I'm at Debian 8.1 but I'm sure that's not correct.